# rxjs shortcut for mapping of one property but streaming the whole object

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to manipulate properties of an object but streaming the whole object

Is there a shortcut for this beauty?

```
Observable.of(data)
  .map((data) => {data.newDueDate = this.filterDate(data.newDueDate); return data;})
  .map((data) => {data.reply = this.generateReply(data.request); return data;})
  ...
```

I am searching for something like this, so i can alter the `data` object in **clear atomic steps**.

```
Observable.of(data)
  .mapProperty('newDueDate' => this.filterDate)
  .mapProperty('reply' => this.generateReply(data.request))
  ...
```

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do`:

```
Observable.of(data)
  .do(data => {
     data.newDueDate = this.filterDate(data.newDueDate);
     data.reply = this.generateReply(data.request);
  })
```

Edit to the comment:

```
Observable.of(data)
  .do(data => data.newDueDate = this.filterDate(data.newDueDate))
  .do(data => data.reply = this.generateReply(data.request))
```

You can do that or create or own custom operator, but I think that's too much.

Comment: thank you, but this is not exactly what i want. I could use `map` this way too and `return data` at the end, but i want clean atomic steps to manipulate the object.

Comment: I think your answer is the closest one. `.do` streams the object and i didn't have to return it all the way. The second part, the explicit operator to archive this is not in the rxjs toolbox by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you could add both manipulations into the first `map()` but I agree it looks kind of lame so you might use `Object.assign()` for example:

```
Observable.of(data)
  .map(d => Object.assign(d, {
    newDueDate: this.filterDate(data.newDueDate),
    reply: this.generateReply(data.request),
  }))
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question to explain better what i want to archive. I am looking for clear atomic steps.

Comment: @fastr.de I don't think there's any operator that could do that. Of course you can write your own but in order to do that I'd recommend upgrading to RxJS 6 first.